# Windows 11 lock screen slideshow always *starts* with the same picture

Tags: windows-11, lock-screen

Under "lock screen" settings, my "Personalize your lock screen" is currently set to "Slideshow". The slideshow works, but only sort of:

The slideshow always *starts off* displaying the latest picture from
the "Picture"-setting under the "Personalize your lock screen" tab.
It then eventually switches to a picture in your designated slideshow folder. Furthermore, when you click to type in your password, it again switches to this same picture. The "Picture" setting is for *if* you want the lock screen to show only show one picture, not a slideshow.

This is annoying for a couple of reasons:

- The picture you've chosen in the "picture" setting may not even be a picture within your designated slideshow folder. It makes no sense to display it first!
- For me, the purpose of a slideshow on the lock screen is to always start off my pc with a new picture (in my case, i have a folder with various background images from Studio Ghibli films i want to switch between). *Starting* with the same picture, and then switching to a new one after the duration it takes me to type in my password defeats the entire point.

**Attempts:**

I've deleted the *NoLockScreenSlideshow* key in RegEdit and i've disabled the various settings in *gpedit.msc* that lock the lock screen slideshow. I've made sure the Slideshow is enabled under power settings and made sure that "Turn off the screen after the slideshow has played for" under Personalization -> lock screen is turned off.

I've tried choosing a picture in the "Picture"-setting, then deleting that chosen picture to "force" Windows to show something else, but the picture is still there. Even if i somehow managed to delete it, there are still a couple of preset images installed with the pc. Under "recent images" in the "Picture"-setting, you can see the latest 5 images. Where is windows secretly storing these pictures, so that we can delete all of them?

EDIT:
I've found the location of the lock-screen pictures.
It's under "*C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\User_Account_Security_Identifier\ReadOnly", and you need to enable hidden folders & files.
Still, i don't know if it's safe to actually delete all the pictures there, or if it would even have the desired effect.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled a few times after being annoyed by this issue myself every so often - think I found the issue (but no fix unfortunately).

From an old thread (2016, see [2nd from bottom post here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-lock-screen-slideshow-not-showing/01975f7f-11e8-457e-a8ef-5b494af135f1?page=2)) that I suspect is still true to this day:

> Howdy!  I wrote this code. You mentioned that the Slideshow always "starts with" the last selected image under Lock Screen -> Background -> Picture.  That is incorrect.  Instead, please understand that the Lock Screen -> Background -> Picture image is shown until the Slideshow itself is ready to start.
>
> This is a feature of the slideshow and how it works.  It is impossible to not have it work this way.  I understand what you're going for here, but -- that is not how it works.  We try to optimize as much as we can, but until the Lock Screen Slideshow has loaded things up and is ready to go we display the selected Picture.  Otherwise you'd be seeing nothing at all for that duration, and that's no fun. :)